# Unable to active Microsoft Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office

I am unable to activate my copy of office 2016 , the app accepts my credentials, but it keep asking me for activate the copy no matter what, during the process it seems the process is correct without giving any kind of error.

I tried with my user, user administrator, local, domain and have also rebooted the PC. I have no antivirus software.

I installed the software from the same office site, with the account to be activated.

Comment: What site did you get it from?

Comment: portal.office.com

Comment: It sounds like you should call the, Microsoft Activation Center, in order to activate your copy of Office 2016.

Comment: My account is a personal version, never had that problem before.

Comment: That doesn't stop @Ramhound suggestion from being great advice

Comment: @AlejandraMoreno - Have you tried my suggestion?  If you have not called the activation center, then you should, and update your question if it doesn't work.